# I have updated the android studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0 and now I am having gradle project sysc failed

Tags: android

[Here is the screen shot of error and I tried to refresh and sysc it but it is not working and taking long time to sysc or refresh.][1]

!  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBQRj.png

Comment: Just update Your gradle

Comment: can you help me, how to update the gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Project's gradle set classpath to :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

And in your gradle-wrapper.properties file use:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

In your app's gradle use

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

Save these changes and try to build. 
If it still fails, Go to File-> Invalidate Caches /Restart.

Comment: My gradle-wrapper.properties file is distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: builtToolVersion '25.0.2' and I do not know where to find the classpath..

Comment: check in your JNECTimeTable gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum support version is 3.3 current version is 3.2
You should update your gradle version to 3.3 or more than that

Comment: can you help me how to upgrade gradle version to 3.3 or +++

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your gradle to 3.3 and then resync your project. This should work.

Comment: I dont know where I can update the gradle and in the gradle-wrapper.properties it is showing distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip but in the gradle home from setting it is showing this-C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-3.2 where I have selected ~use local gradle distribution

Answer (score 0):

Open the build.gradle file for the project directory.
Inside the

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:version'
```

version should match with the exact version located inside the

> ....\android-studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle

Comment: I did not understand what you mean cause I am in confuse state

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command from your terminal:

./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 3.3